# Can the school see what you do on the school's Google account even on your own device and at home?

Tags: account-security, google

I was on my normal gmail account that I always use, then this website opened my google docs app which was signed into my school account and it put some weird stuff on there like “i’m the hottest girl in school” weird messages.

Can the school see that that document got put on there although it was not my school laptop or their wifi it was just my gmail that opened the doc?

Answer (score 2):

The Google account is administered by the school and they have access to everything created under the account and it doesn't matter what device you use or what wifi you connect to. It's all under the Google account.

But it is very unlikely that the admins will inspect every document unless what is entered triggers some kind of alert in their system, but that will likely be about illegal activities, porn, or bullying. If they even have those types of triggers set up.

So, no, “i’m the hottest girl in school” is not likely going to be noticed.